# Increasing application timeout for asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

In my application, I make A service call which may take upto 2 mins To return value. (process Take Place across multiple databases).

Upon calling this method the application times out.

I have set the following in web config. still i am getting the error when hosted in IIS

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <sessionState timeout="40"></sessionState>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="3600"/>

</system.web>
```

I have set the same execution timeout in service web.config as well
please help me in increasing the time out for the application.

Comment: Do you have an binding section in the web.config for the service? if so, post that.

Comment: if the return takes 2 minutes then you have bad design. Solve this, make the work on background, keep cache, and other...

Comment: @Aristos - Without knowing anything about his program or what it's doing how can you possibly make the assumption it's bad design? Some calls will take a long time to complete depending on the actions on the other end of the service. This is the whole point of the time out properties ...

Comment: @webnoob I am not assump anything, I say that this is bad design. If you do not understand that, then you probably do it also, and for that reason you react, better stay back to your chair and say, "why this is a bad design, what this guy knows that I don't and I must learn" ?

Comment: @Aristos - If a process on the other end of a service takes 5 minutes to complete (and you have no control over that), what are the options other than to wait for it to complete?

Comment: @webnoob Apparently there is a way to wait that 5 minutes work. :) Actually there are at least 2-3 ways that I have made. The most easy to make is to run the work on the background, show the results after this ends.

Comment: I Actually access around  60 server each having 6 - 10 databases On average To validate a users A existance and get details if Exists. so the process takes Around 2 mins.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried setting the shutdownTimeout value in the httpRuntime section?
The default shutdown time of an idle application is 90 seconds.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" shutdownTimeout="360" executionTimeout="3600"/>
```

MSDN Reference:
[HttpRuntimeSection.ShutdownTimeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.shutdowntimeout%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
```

Set debug="false" should solve the problem.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Execution Timeout: Optional Int32 attribute.
>       Specifies the maximum number of seconds that a request is allowed to execute before being automatically shut down by ASP.NET.
>       This time-out applies only if the debug attribute in the compilation element is False. Therefore, if the debug attribute is
>   True, you do not have to set this attribute to a large value in order
>   to avoid application shutdown while you are debugging.
>       The default is 110 seconds.
>       Note:
>       In the .NET Framework 1.0 and 1.1, the default is 90 seconds.

Comment: Tried to set debug to false .still no use appliaciton Times out in 90 secs

Comment: When setting debug=true the executionTimeout is ignored

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="1200" />
```

the callback to update the browser for the client has a default timeout (90 seconds) in the script manager. so if your code behind is running the full page but the browser does not update, then this tag might help.

Comment: You should add some text explaining what this answer does and why it provides a solution to the specific problem. Code dumps are rarely ever of use to other people.